# Need help installing go/golang bindings for llvm

Tags: go, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to use the Go llvm bindings from https://github.com/go-llvm/llvm
I've done everything the README tells me to do, but for some reason the installation fails.

[image]

it seems like I don't have access to the llvm repository (?)
how can I fix this?
Thanks